# Codeignitor-4 API - POST request getting 403 error

Tags: php, codeigniter

i'm new here and to CI4 and API requests. When i try to send a POST request to CI4 using postmanits giving me a 403 error. GET method requests works find

Controller

```
namespace App\Controllers;

use CodeIgniter\RESTful\ResourceController;
use CodeIgniter\API\ResponseTrait;

class Myapi extends ResourceController
{

    protected $modelName = 'App\Models\UserModel';
    protected $format    = 'json';

    use ResponseTrait;

    public function index()
    {
        $data = [
            'message'   => 'Success',
            'all_users' => $this->model->findAll()
        ];

        return $this->respond($data, 200);
    }

    public function show($id = null)
    {
        return $this->respond($this->model->find($id), 200);
    }

    public function create()
    {
        $data = $this->model->insert([
            'first_name'            => esc($this->request->getVar('first_name')),
            'email'                 => esc($this->request->getVar('email')),
            'password'              => esc($this->request->getVar('password')),
            'password_confirmation' => esc($this->request->getVar('password_confirmation'))
        ]);

        $response = [
            'message'   => 'User inserted',
            '$data'     => $data
        ];

        return $this->respondCreated($response);
    }
```

Routing

```
$routes->get('myapi', 'Myapi::index');
$routes->post('myapi', 'Myapi::create');
```

Postman request

```
{
    "first_name": "api name",
    "email": "api@api.lk",
    "password": "Test@test",
    "password_confirmation": "Test@test"
}
```

I want to insert the data to the DB from the API call

Comment: 403 means it's not allowed, which for POST requests in CI4 means that CSRF is turned on.  https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/security.html?highlight=csrf#config-for-csrf